# vBulletin - update forum password not working

Tags: forum, vbulletin

My question is more theoretical, because I am not sure what is wrong. Here is my goal:

I have a password protected forum. I have a script that runs once a week and it is a simple statement:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE vb_forum SET password=$password WHERE forumid='28'");
```

That changes the password for the forum in the database; however, when a user goes to that forum and enters the new password - it doesn't work. I have to go to admincp and edit that forum (the password field is already filled in with the updated password.) Without changing anything I hit save and then the new password takes effect.

I am wondering what is it that vbulletin does that I don't in my code?

Any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after doing a search on the entire database. It appears I have to update value in the vb_datastore table as well